# Recommended design approach for web service downloading/importing within app

Tags: android

My app needs to initially download data from two different web services (JSON) and import them into it's local database (Realm). I have two activities that need to display data from these web services. The first one (HomeActivity) is the initial activity that the app loads. The second one (LineupActivity) is created when navigating to it from the HomeActivity.

Currently, I've created an Application class (extending Application) in order to handle the web service downloading and importing. In it's onCreate(), it calls two methods, which are AsyncTasks that download and import each web service.

The reason I've added this download/import process into the Application class is for 2 reasons:

1. I want all the app data to be downloaded as soon as possible, so
   when navigating to the second activity it doesn't need to initiate
   another download.
2. Both these activities have swipe to refresh. They call each respective method in the Application class to re-download/import the
   web service data.

Have I approached this incorrectly? Should I move the web service download/import logic out of the Application class? Also, does the onCreate() of the Application class get called more than once? Meaning, I know that it only gets called only once in the application's lifecycle, but does the Android OS eventually kill an app and have it call the onCreate() in the Application class when starting it again? I want the app to download fresh data upon startup, but not every time the user brings the app into focus.

Comment: `Application.onCreate()` will not be called "everytime the application gets into focus", but only when the OS re-creates the app; and yes, this could happen if your application was off for a while and the OS needed some memory for example. Anyway, this is the right place to initialize stuff IMO. The rest is a matter of opinion, I don't think it's an overhaul bad implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Have I approached this incorrectly?**
"Incorrectly" is a very relative term in this context.
*Metaphorically, its like the `context` is never `null` but that doesn't determine `boolean` incorrect is true or false.*

**Should I move the web service download/import logic out of the Application class?**
I would say Yes, as the download logic would not be related to the O.S. and the app being alive in its memory. Your requirement does not seem complex. `Service` would be necessary if the downloads are huge chunks of data, and if its not necessary, don't do it.

**Also, does the onCreate() of the Application class get called more than once? Meaning, I know that it only gets called only once in the application's lifecycle...Application class when starting it again?**
No, it won't be called more than once without app being killed and restarted. And what your are saying is correct, but for your requirement, there are probably more efficient and lighter ways to do it rather than combining it with an `Application` class.

---

For the rest of the logic, you could implement Asynctasks as a separate class and implement interfaces which are the callbacks of the result of your task. This would help in Swipe-to-refresh functionality.

In terms of documentation reference, [Application class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)

> There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situation,
>   static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular
>   way.

Your case seems exactly that.

One thing you need to decide is *When*, *how often* do you need to refresh/download the data. For only start-up of the app or once daily, you can store date/day in `SharedPreferences` and check the value in `onResume()` of your `Activity`.

You can also implement inheritance with a Base Activity with the necessary download check logic in it and extend your classes. A Splash Screen would always help to initiate the downloads.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could approach this anyway you want, though I like to implement one of the three options mentioned here: https://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-developing-RESTful-android-apps.pdf.

The presentation itself can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE.

This does however not mention how you should sync on startup. But you could just set a SharedPreference in the application class and then use one of the patterns to sync in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you instead of using Application to download your stuff to use a [Service](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html). If by any reason your app gets killed by the OS your dl's will never complete. Using a Service it will.

Also, you can use a [Broadcast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html#sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)) to your activity to s[ignalize that the service has completed downloading and taking the necessary following steps](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/report-status.html).

Answer (score 0):

**first:** I think it's bad to place the download at appliaction onCreate
as stated in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate())

> Called when the application is starting, before any activity, service,
>   or receiver objects (excluding content providers) have been created.
>   Implementations should be as quick as possible (for example using lazy
>   initialization of state) since the time spent in this function
>   directly impacts the performance of starting the first activity,
>   service, or receiver in a process. If you override this method, be
>   sure to call super.onCreate().

pay attention to this part
**Implementations should be as quick as possible (for example using lazy initialization of state) since the time spent in this function directly impacts the performance of starting the first activity**
so any delay in download or import may cause the first activity to be delayed.
and the behavior is not clear, a black screen maybe?

**Second** suggestions for download/import:
1- use an AsyncTask in the first activity, where you display a small progress bar indicating the download/import process or even block the whole UI until completed (based on your business)

2- add a splash screen while downloading the data

regarding fresh data, you can store a timestamp, last_updated
and before starting the download/import process, check that value, if less than your accepted value (say 1 hour) don't start the download/import.

**finally**, regarding onCreate() call, i think it's not called everytime, only when app is re-created, like 1st run after reboot, or after being killed or forced close.